# ImageNet test dataset for keras applications models

Tags: keras, imagenet

I have a model pretrained on ImageNet like this:

```
from keras.applications import resnet50
model = resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
```

Is there any way to get test ImageNet dataset and their labels (which means data not used for training the above `model`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original

Sadly ImageNet ([from ILSVRC2012](http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/downloads)) never released the labels for the 100k images in the test dataset. You  can use instead the 50k images from the Validation dataset, whose labels can be found in the `Develpoment Kit (tasks 1 and 2)`.

You can download both the Validation images and the validation labels from http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/downloads

#### Updated!

There is an ImageNet Test set with 100k images available [here](http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/), and although you cannot access the labels, you can instead predict the labels for all the images and submit your predictions for evaluation (top1, top5) [here](http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2013/test_server).

Comment: A not-very-relevant question. Is there any version of Tiny ImageNet in original size of ImageNet? 256*256 instead of 64*64.

Comment: Not that I know of

Answer (score 0):

You can load a model with weights=None and [download](http://www.image-net.org/) imagenet dataset.You can then split the dataset into train-test, train your model with train set and use test set for your purpose